# how to create bottom line border in multiple textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm just beginner in Objective C.
I want to create multiple textfield  with only bottom line border.
for this i crete a new class `customTextField`
look at my code;-

`CustomTextField.m`

```
- (id)init {
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
border.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
[self.layer addSublayer:border];
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

return self;

}
```

in my `loginViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomTextField *txtFirstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomTextField *txtLastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomTextField *txtEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomTextField *txtPassword;

@end
```

`loginViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];      

   _txtFirstName = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
    _txtLastName = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
    _txtEmail = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
    _txtPassword = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];


}
```

I don't know where I do mistakes. this code is doing nothing. Can any one tell me where I do wrong ?
any help or any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
```

But you're using IBOulet, which means your objects are initialised from the storyboard, so then you should move your code to `awakeFromNib`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting you .

Comment: You have instantiated your objects as `IBOulets` which means you're linking them in your storyboard or xib file, right? Then you *don't* have to initialise them with this `[[CustomTextField alloc] init]`, and instead of adding the code to `- (id)init` you should move it to `- (void)awakeFromNib`, in your custom class

Comment: no change only one textfield changed else remain same.

Comment: Are the objects properly linked in your storyboard?

Comment: And did you set the class of your objects in the storyboard as `CustomTextField `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88351/discussion-between-subhash-sharma-and-pablo-a).

Answer (score 0):

Add a private border layer property in your .m file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CALayer *borderLayer;
```

Override `layoutSubviews` to set up the border.

```
- (void)layoutSubViews {
    [super layoutSubViews];
    if (self.borderLayer) {
        self.borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }
    CGFloat borderWidth = 5.0f;
    self.borderLayer.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;
    self.borderLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
}
```

**Update**:
Don't initialize the `CustomTextField IBOutlets` in viewDidLoad. Simply set their class to `CustomTextField` in the storyboard!

Comment: can you please explain it more, what to do ?

Comment: sure:
override layoutSubviews in your textField. It is called whenever the view needs to be resized. Probably fixes your problem, that there is no border.

Comment: Or does your code not even do anything? are you using storyboard?

Comment: Can you please clearify by "the code does nothing"? are no views visible? 
Did you set the correct class for the textfields in the storyboard?

Comment: I just saw: 
    _txtFirstName = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
    _txtLastName = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
    _txtEmail = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
    _txtPassword = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];
is not necessary in the viewDidLoad! Set the correct class for the textfields in the storyboard

Comment: "the code does nothing" means the textfield is there but no border set and  I already removed  `_txtFirstName = [[CustomTextField alloc]init]; _txtLastName = [[CustomTextField alloc]init]; _txtEmail = [[CustomTextField alloc]init]; _txtPassword = [[CustomTextField alloc]init];` this code and what your mean to right class, is  `customTextfield`  not a right class?

Comment: Yes it is, but you have to specify in your storyboard that the textfield should be of class CustomTextField

Answer (score 0):

you are using subclass with storyboard your code will fine if you create all button programatically but if you want that your code will work fine with story board and programatically then you have to use this code in your `CustomTextField.m`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self initialize];
}


- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [self initWithFrame:self.frame];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initialize
{
   CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
   CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
   border.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
   border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
   [self.layer addSublayer:border];
   self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Calling `initialize` in `layoutSuviews`? That's just soooo wrong. `layoutSubviews` is called multiple times, so you'll end up adding a new `CALayer` each time.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer didn't you see `[view removeFromSuperview];` in `layoutSubViews`

Comment: I did. My assumption was that it was for something else. Iterating over `subviews` will **not** give you any border layer you have added. You will have to iterate over `sublayers` and find the specific `borderLayer`. Debug the view and you'll see you have added multiple `CALayer`s.

Comment: I think it will remove every view inside the self, I don't have to time to test it but if there is any problem programmer knows that how to remove the extra view/layer from the view. I think everyone can do this without any problem, here we can't give exact solution after testing everything, It's just the basic idea.